# trouble when using anonymous functions inside erlang modules

Tags: erlang, anonymous-function

i was working with anonymous functionss in erlang when a problem caught my attention.
the function is defined as  follows

```
-module(qt). 
-export([ra/0]). 
ra = fun() -> 4 end.
```

this however does not work

```
-export(Ra/0]). 
Ra = fun() -> 4 end.
```

and neither does this 
can anyone tell me why erlang exhibits this behaviour ?

Answer (score 5):

An Erlang module cannot export variables, only functions.

You can achieve something similar to exporting variables by exporting a function with zero arguments that simply returns a value (an anonymous function is a valid return value):

```
-module(qt).
-export([ra/0]).
ra() ->
    fun() -> 4 end.
```

Now you can use it from the shell:

```
1> c(qt).
{ok,qt}
2> qt:ra().
#Fun<qt.0.111535607>
3> (qt:ra())().
4
```

Comment: Though Erlang calls those names as variables, their values cannot be updated. So there is no use in exposing anything like this.

Comment: so erlang considers this is as assignment to a variable and not as a function and hence refuses to export it ?

Comment: @draklor40 Refuses to compile, even.  In an Erlang module, variable assignments can only appear within functions.

Comment: @Dmitry Erlang will never let you update any variable. What do you mean ?    draklor40 you can only export functions, that's all. The main error is that you can't compile example code from the OP. Erlang won't let you write code like assignments in the body of a module. Modules aren't scripts, they only define things (functions, types, records) and eventually export things.

Comment: @niahoo There is no assignment operation in Erlang but bindings. There is no rebinds too and every usage of a name after the first is just retrieving the value that is binded to that name. It's impossible to overwrite a value in Erlang too. All that means that there are no destructive updates in Erlang except in special storages like ETS.